# Dynamic addClass() from selectbox

Tags: jquery, css, dynamic, drop-down-menu

Hopefully this isn't a repeat question, but if it is, just post the link as your response.

I need to create a website with a select dropdown as the top with a few options, and several divs below with several links in them.

Depending on which option you select in the selectbox, the links that are labeled appropriately will get highlighted.

Here's the basic structure:

```
<select>
  <option value="o1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="o2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="o3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="o4">Option 4</option>
</select> 

<div>
  <a href="#" class="o1">Link A</a>
  <a href="#" class="o2">Link B</a>
  <a href="#" class="o3">Link C</a>
  <a href="#" class="o4">Link D</a>
</div>

<div>
   <a href="#" class="o1">Link A</a>
   <a href="#" class="o2">Link B</a>
   <a href="#" class="o3">Link C</a>
   <a href="#" class="o4">Link D</a>
</div>
```

I know this process will include the .addClass() .removeClass() and .change(), I'm just not sure how to put it all together so that it works dynamically across all the divs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Link so:

```
$('select').on('change', function(){
    var klass = this.value;
    $('.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
    $('a.'+klass).addClass('highlight');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('select').on('change', function() {      // binding change event for select
                                           // fires when select box change

  var mycls = this.value;                  // getting the value of select 
                                           // box after change



  $('a:not(".'+ mycls +'")')               // select <a> tag that has no 
                                           // class same as select box value
              .removeClass('some_class');  // and remove highlight 
                                           // class form that <a>

  $('a.' + mycls)                          // select the <a> with class 
                                           // same as select box value
             .addClass('some_class');      // and adding highlight class
});
```

To make initially a link highlight just trigger an initial change

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
  var mycls = this.value;
  $('a:not(".'+ mycls +'")').removeClass('some_class');
  $('a.' + mycls).addClass('some_class');
}).change(); // here the initial change event triggered
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/dQYK6/4/)**

Comment: @Murphy1976 I add necessary comment to my answer, you don't need to add it in your code. Add just simply.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you already answered the question in the last sentence but here is that next step.

You have to add the .change() event handler to your select box.

```
$("select").change(function () {

});
```

Then when that even happens read the selected value and since you named them the same apply the style to that class.

```
$("select").change(function () {
    $( "." + $(this).attr("value") ).css("background", "#ccc");
}
```

Comment: you need to remove class otherwise it will stay highlited

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you gave the select list an id e.g. selectid
and you had a class called .highlight, you could do something like:

```
$('#selectid').change(function(){

  $('*').removeClass('highlight');

  $('.'+$(this).val()).addClass('highlight'); 

});
```

I've not tested the above but it should put you on the right track.